# Prove that: $\int_a^bf(x)dx = 2\int_{a}^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx$ for a symmetric continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, solution-verification

> Given a continuous function $f(x)$ defined on a range $x\in[a,b]$, such that the function has equal values in points symmetric to $x = {a+b\over 2}$, prove that:
>   $$
> \int_a^bf(x)dx = 2\int_{a}^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx
> $$

I've started by using the fundamental theorem of calculus, namely:
$$
\int_a^bf(x)dx = \int_a^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx + \int_{a+b\over 2}^bf(x)dx = \\
F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(a) +F(b) - F\left({a+b\over 2}\right)
$$

On the other hand:
$$
2\int_{a}^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx = 2\left(F\left({a+b\over 2}\right)- F(a)\right) \\
= F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(a) + F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(a)
$$

Since the function is symmetric with respect to $x_0$ then:
$$
F(a) = F(b) \tag 1
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{align}
I &= F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(a) + F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(b) \\
&= F\left({a+b\over 2}\right) - F(a) - \left(F(b) - F\left({a+b\over 2}\right)\right)\\ 
&=\int_a^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx - \int_{a+b\over 2}^bf(x)dx \tag2
\end{align}
$$

Which is obviously nonsense. I believe the error is in $(1)$

So in case, the sign in $(2)$ is plus as opposed to minus then:
$$
\int_a^{a+b\over 2}f(x)dx + \int_{a+b\over 2}^bf(x)dx = \int_a^bf(x)dx
$$

Is the idea to prove the statement "correct in general"? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Symmetric with respect to the POINT $(x_0, f(x_0)$ or the line $x=x_0$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron with respect to the line $x= x_0$. so $f({a+b\over 2} - \delta) = f({a+b\over 2}+ \delta)$ for $\delta > 0$

Comment: Why don't you make a change of variables in the second integral $x=t+a-\frac{a+b}{2}=t+\frac{a-b}{2}$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron what kind of variable change do you mean?

Comment: Hint: Change of variable is also called $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the seconf integral, do the next C.V.
$t=a+b-x$: so that $dx=-dt$ and for $x=b$ $t=a$ and for $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ $t=\frac{a+b}{2}$. So

$$\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^bf(x)dx = -\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{a}f(a+b-t)dt = \int_a^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{a+b}{2}-t\right)}_{>0}\right)dt = 
\int_a^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}-\left(\frac{a+b}{2}-t\right)\right)dt =\int_a^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f(t)dt
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to finish using your hint from the comments.